# Javascript loop an object array and return a new array

Tags: javascript, arrays

To use react, I have an object array like this:

```
   {
    _id: 1,
    items: [

              { goodName: "cake", amount: 10 },
              { goodName: "potato", amount: 11 },
              { goodName: "apple", amount: 15 }
           ]
    }
    {
    _id: 2,
    items: [

              { goodName: "cake", amount: 10 },
              { goodName: "potato", amount: 11 },
              { goodName: "apple", amount: 15 }
           ]
    }
    {
    _id: 3,
    items: [

              { goodName: "cake", amount: 10 },
              { goodName: "potato", amount: 11 },
              { goodName: "apple", amount: 15 }
           ]
    }
```

Now, I want to loop through this object array，and return an array
containing the amount's accumulated value of each good.I want to use `.map()` methods to make it like this:

```
 var value = items.map(function(item) {
                var amounts = 0;
                var amount=[];
                for (var i=0; i<=myArr.length; i++) {
                    if (myArr[i] === item.name) {
                        amounts=amounts+item.amount;
                        amount.push(amounts);
                    }
                }
            })
```

But it doesn't work. `myArr` is an array I use the `new Set()` and
`Array.from()` method to loop through the `goodName` and return it. I don't know what method I use can make it, is everyone has another way?

Comment: You're using `map` on items but you aren't returning anything from the map callback function. You're supposed to return something from inside the callback. Check the docs: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Comment: Where it comes from myArr ? What it contains?

Comment: please add the wanted result.

Comment: you can use nested forEach for this

Answer (score 3):

I have written code to loop over your information and return tallies of the total amounts of each good type. However, several clarifications are required.

- The information in your question needs to be wrapped in square brackets, as the outer objects you show need to be elements in an array.
- I am returning an object, not an array as you suggest in your question. That allows the `results` to contain information about *which* items each tally corresponds to, i.e. `{good1: total1, good2: total2, ...}`
- I include an extra (fourth) object just to show that the code requires neither the same number of goods nor even the same identities of goods in each array element.

```js
var arr = [
  {_id: 1, items: [
    {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
    {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
    {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
  ]},
  {_id: 2, items: [
    {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
    {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
    {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
  ]},
  {_id: 3, items: [
    {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
    {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
    {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
  ]},
  {_id: 4, items: [
    {goodName: "potato", amount: 1000},
    {goodName: "peach",  amount: 2000}
  ]}
];

var results = {};
arr.forEach(arrElmt => {
  arrElmt.items.forEach(item => {
    results[item.goodName] = (results[item.goodName] || 0) + item.amount;
  });
});
var res = JSON.stringify(results);

console.log(res);
```

Comment: Please, use console.log instead of document.write in the snippet so I can see the message with my smartphone. +1

Comment: @gaetanoM I used `document.write` for speed, but I've now changed it to both `document.body.innerHTML = ...` and `console.log(...)`. I'm not always sure what can be seen in what contexts (e.g. mobile), so hopefully one or both of these will help.

Comment: Sorry, I tried to update your snippet, and only now I understood the problem: on windows mobile 8.1 the es 6 does not work (i.e.: let, => and so on). Sorry again, it would  have been a pleasure to have this possibility. Please, update your snippet so my name will disappear.  Thanks again for your patience.

Comment: @gaetanoM No problem. Actually, I go back and forth between using ES5 and ES6 in my SO questions/answers...should I make code backwards compatible or the latest/greatest (but also reasonably stable)? Hmm. In any case, your suggestion about `console.log` was new to me, i.e. I didn't know you could do that on SO. So, I dug a bit and found [this Q/A about console.log](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/239706). Very cool. I'm still not 100% clear on how I should show results in SO, but this is food for thought. So thanks very much for that, even if that wasn't your intended purpose!

Answer (score 0):

You can't use only map, because you are accumulating the values of the items. I would use reduce:

```js
const arr = [
      {_id: 1, items: [
        {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
        {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
        {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
      ]},
      {_id: 2, items: [
        {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
        {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
        {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
      ]},
      {_id: 3, items: [
        {goodName: "cake",   amount: 10},
        {goodName: "potato", amount: 11},
        {goodName: "apple",  amount: 15}
      ]},
      {_id: 4, items: [
        {goodName: "potato", amount: 1000},
        {goodName: "peach",  amount: 2000}
      ]}
    ];
    
    let results = [].concat.apply([], arr.map(elem => elem.items))
        .reduce((results, item) => {
            results[item.goodName] = (results[item.goodName] || 0) + item.amount;
            return results;
        }, {});
    document.write(JSON.stringify(results));
```

JS does not have `flatMap`, so the `[].concat.apply` dance is a little weird, but any good library will have it.